# What is the value of the responseJson returned by a fetch statement if no date are inside the JSON file

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch, response, jsonresponse

What is the value of the responseJson returned by a fetch statement if no date are inside the JSON file. Is it an empty array or just null?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the value returned from the fetch statement. Does it returns an empty array or a null value?

The response will be serialized based on that.